# Pass data from one page to another in Ionic 4

Tags: tabs, ionic4

I am currently working on an Ionic 4 project. I have data in a button named `button1` in the side menu. I want to display the data of that button in a separate page named `tab1`. How can I do this in Ionic 4 framework?

Ps: I have data arriving in `button1`. I want the same data to be displayed in the page `tab1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 pushTab(params: any) {
        this.navCtrl.push(Tab1Page,params);
 }
```

And in your tab page :

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
             public navParams: NavParams){
  var data = navParams.data;
}
```